# Insert special characters into a string variable ASP Classic

Tags: utf-8, asp-classic, vbscript, base64, symbols

I have a string variable that is french:

```
objMail.Subject = "Confirmation d’une demande de réservation d’une maison de villégiature     pour"
```

This is the subject of an email sent to clients.

the problem is that when they get the email the special characters "e" and " ' "
they are not converted into their respective symbols.

How do I correct this? any special codes?

EDIT:  this is the VBScript code

```
    Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("CDONTS.NewMail")

objMail.BodyFormat = 0
objMail.MailFormat = 0

objMail.To = email
objMail.From = "Vacation.Homes@gwl.ca"


objMail.Cc = "Vacation.Homes@gwl.ca"

If Session("ACCESS_LEVEL") = "A" Then
    objMail.Subject = "Confirmation of Vacation Homes request submitted for " & strEEName
ElseIf Session("LANG") = "FR" THEN
    objMail.Subject = "Confirmation d’une demande de reservation d’une maison de villegiature pour"
Else
    objMail.Subject = "Confirmation of Vacation Homes request received"
End If

objMail.Body = strMessageText

objMail.Send

WriteLogMsg ">>>>>>>>> CONFIRMATION EMAIL SENT TO " & email & " <<<<<<<<<< (SubmitRequest.asp)"

Set objMail = Nothing
```

Comment: Save your asp file with UTF encode, the asp file is a clear text file, so the text editor that you use, must have this ability to save it with utf encode.

Comment: Could you post more of the code you use to set up the email? You might be sending it as plain text, which would account for the problem noted.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add that this is VBScript, also I'll add more code

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a general e-mail question and isn't specific to ASP3. What you need is to encode the subject in UTF-8 in the subject itself, like this:

```
objMail.Subject = "=?UTF-8?B?" & Base64Encode("Confirmation d’une demande de réservation d’une maison de villégiature pour") & "?="
```

Note that the original string (i.e. your code page) needs to be encoded in UTF-8 as well.